# Getting an error when i call a structure variable by using pointer with array subscription

Tags: c++, pointers

```
// Menu Structure

struct Menu 
{

   char* name;

   void (*func) ();
};

Menu* tmpPtr = NULL;

// Menu Function prototypes

void fileFunction();

void editFunction();

void viewFunction();

void exitFunction();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   unsigned selection = 0 ;

   Menu menuStruct[] = {  

      {"file", fileFunction},

      {"edit", editFunction},

      {"view", viewFunction},

      {"exit", exitFunction}  };

   tmpPtr = menuStruct;


   while(selection != 4)
   {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
      {
         std::cout << i+1 <<" : " << tmpPtr->name << std::endl;
         tmpPtr++;

      }
      tmpPtr = menuStruct;


      std::cout<< "Enter Selection Value: " ;
      std::cin>>selection;

      if(selection <= 4)
         *(tmpPtr[selection-1]->func)();

   }   

   return 0;
}
```

Error received: **base operand of '->' has non pointer type Menu**

But it is working when i use  (**(tmpPtr+selection-1)->func)(); as far as my knowledge both are same,

I donno why this error is coming, please help me to figure out the mistake am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
     *(tmpPtr[selection-1]->func)();
```

is a problem since the type of `tmpPtr[selection-1]` is `Menu`, not `Menu*`. You need to use:

```
     *(tmpPtr[selection-1].func)();
```

**Update**

Due to operator precedence, the line

```
     *(tmpPtr[selection-1].func)();
```

is the same as

```
     *((tmpPtr[selection-1].func)());
```

Since the return type of `Menu:func` is `void`, that line is equivalent to:

```
    *(void)
```

which is not right.

You can use:

```
     (*tmpPtr[selection-1].func)();
```

or, simply:

```
     tmpPtr[selection-1].func();
```

Comment: when i used . operator it is showing the error "void value not ignored as it ought to be". why?